# Can we have a formatting sandbox?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jtab

Specifically for getting jTab blocks to look right without blowing through the revision-limit, I think it would be useful to have a CW sandbox question on the main site (since jTab isn't enabled on meta).

Thoughts?

Option 2: Enable jTab on meta. Then we could make a sandbox without the messiness.

Comment: Related: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/396/133, http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/240/133

Comment: Huh, I guess I assumed it was enabled on Meta.  I don't see any reason for it not to be.

Comment: @MatthewRead I've edited the question. Would "enabling jtab on meta" be better as a separate request?

Comment: I think it's fine here.

Comment: Another one http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208/formatting-sand-box

Answer (score 4):

I think that creating a dummy question on main would be too messy, and difficult to teach new users about. I don't know if other SE's have done stuff like that before, but I'd like to hear about it.

This page is a complete explanation of all jTab grammar complete with a parser up at the top.

http://jtab.tardate.com/examples.htm

I realize a lot of the annoyance is from how jTab is implemented on Music.SE in particular, but here are the simple rules:

- jTab will activate on all code blocks, and will display tab imagery for anything it can parse in those code blocks.
- To avoid this, use `<pre></pre>` HTML tags.
- If you want line breaks in your jTab, you need to exit the code block completely and give yourself a couple of newlines before the next code block.

Comment: There is one on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox), so there is precedent. I agree, though, that it wouldn't make sense to have it on the main site.

Comment: To be explicit about how 'To avoid this': you need to use `pre` **and also do not indent by four spaces**!